# Image from a link not showing in html2pdf

Tags: javascript, html2pdf

I'm trying to generate a pdf in javascript using [html2pdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html2pdf.js/v/0.9.0) that I installed using npm.
The problem is that it will not show my images that comes from an url in my pdf. Here is my code:
[image: My print function that generates a pdf of my data]

And here is a sandbox showing the issue:
https://codesandbox.io/s/html2pdf-not-loading-image-gvmx0u

As you can see when you click on "export in pdf" the image hard coded in the content variable didn't get into the file..

The result is a pdf file with blank spaces instead of images. Does anyone know how to get my images into the pdf ? Is there a better library in js to build pdf from html ?

Comment: Please may you replace the image with a text-based [mcve]?

Comment: @evolutionxbox I edited the question with a link to a sandbox showing the issue

Comment: Hello @KJ Can you explain what you did there ? Is it an image in base64 hosted online ? Where is the link to it ?

Comment: How could I avoid CORS for jsPDF ? Would it work if I use an xmlhttprequest to get the image first and then build the pdf ?

Comment: The problem is that in my web app I retrieve the urls of my images from an API, which I then want the user to be able to get them in a pdf file. Not sure how I can manage this with jspdf..
Is there another library to use in that case ? Should I use require.context ?

Comment: allow Cors in html2pdf options: [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51791583/pdf-does-not-show-images-html2pdf-library)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For those wondering I resolved the problem by converting images in Base64 and use promises to put it in the html content of the html2pdf.

The whole answer is available in the sandbox of the original question:
https://codesandbox.io/s/html2pdf-not-loading-image-gvmx0u

Here are the sources that helped (as well as what @KJ told me in the comments):

How to convert images in base64: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20285053/5065874

How to await the xmlhhtprequest: [In JavaScript how do I/should I use async/await with XMLHttpRequest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48969495/in-javascript-how-do-i-should-i-use-async-await-with-xmlhttprequest)

Again, thank you KJ for the help !

Answer (score 9):

I fixed this issue by putting

```
useCORS: true

  exportToPDF() {
        var opt = {
            margin: 0,
            filename: 'time_sheet_report.pdf',
            image: { type: 'jpeg', quality: 0.20 },
            html2canvas: { scale: 2,useCORS: true },
            jsPDF: { unit: 'in', format: 'a4', orientation: 'p' }
        };

        html2pdf().set(opt).from(this.$refs.document).save();
}
```

Comment: Just so you know, if the website domain differs from the image URL domain, this is the best answer and works. Otherwise, it's not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I've just overcome this issue with a third approach. The base64 method by Zarcoin, whilst it worked for me, caused browser out of memory issues with large images (Edge).

Converting the images to blob URL has worked in this case. Below is my implementation where I need to convert arrays of image URLs to blobURL

```
const processImages = async (imagesArray) => {
  if (!imagesArray || imagesArray.length === 0) return;
  for (let i = 0; i < imagesArray.length; i++) {
    const imgURL = imagesArray[i].image;
    const image = await fetch(imgURL);
    const imageBlob = await image.blob();
    const blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(imageBlob);
    imagesArray[i].image = blobUrl;
  }
};
```